# BLS curve with a smaller modulus?

Tags: elliptic-curves, pairings

To achieve approximately 128 bits of security, curve BLS12-381 uses 381 bits to encode the X coordinate. This means the size of a group element needs at least 48B to store/transmit.

I am in a situation of trying to transmit a $G_1$ element in the IP packet level, where size is *very* critical, and 48B is somehow too large.

Is there any pairing friendly curve that has smaller $q$ value so as to have a smaller group element? If not, is there any compression-like workaround? This may decrease the bit security but the usability is more important to me now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aurore Guillevic has provided a useful table of [pairing-friendly curves at the 128-bit security level](https://members.loria.fr/AGuillevic/pairing-friendly-curves/#pairing-friendly-curves-at-the-128-bit-security-level) (thanks to @fgrieu for pointing this out to me). They devote a section to curves with the smallest $G_1$ and there are 2 examples with 286-bit $q$ (specifically `BW-19-p286` and `BLS48`). Even more extremely, if we drop slightly below 128-bits of security to allow a 255-bit group there is the `KSS4` construction with 283-bit $q$. Each of these would fit in 36B.